# Why is resorting really required when inserting sorted rows into a sorted database table, if the rows are not appended in the end?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, sorting, amazon-redshift

Let's assume we have a sorted table A and a sorted table B and we want to insert all rows of B in A.

From what I have read so far (correct me if I am wrong), inserting the rows in A from B will result in an unsorted table, unless the sort key values of B are all larger than the maximum sort key value of A (e.g. B is the continuation of the time series A and the sort key is a timestamp).

Based on my understanding, it should be possible to merge the rows of B in A in any case, while keeping the resulting array sorted by inserting each of B's elements in A, one at a time. This should result in lower computational complexity than appending everything and running a generic sorting algorithm

However, I could not find any option for performing an operation like this on databases such as Redshift or MySQL. Is something like that possible? If not, why is that? Are there constraints that make such an idea inefficient?

Comment: How data is stored on disk is not related to/covered by the SQL _language_.

Comment: No. According to relational theory, table rows do not have inherent ordering. In simple terms, tables are not Excel sheets. It's only when you retrieve rows that you can specify in which order you want **to see them**.

Comment: I find both comments generic and confusing. Maybe it was a dumb question, but it was not a yes or no question. What do you mean tables do not have ordering?

Comment: @MattSt Exactly that. The rows of a relational table **do not have order** . In the absence of an `ORDER BY` clause in the query, the database is free to return the rows in any order, every time you retrieve them. Moreover, any "default" ordering you are getting is subject to change without notice.

Comment: @TheImpaler sorry, you had not updated your comment when I replied. From what I know a sortkey can be used to order a table column and its data in order to make future joins more efficient. Isn't that inherent ordering of the table data?

Comment: @MattSt Maybe you are talking about the internal organization of the heap of a table, that is called "clustered table" (in PostgreSQL); however, PostgreSQL does "the best effort" for it, but does not ensure it; it may nevertheless improve query performance. However, I'm not sure if Redshift can work like that.

Answer (score 3):

Since this question is tagged with Amazon Redshift I'm going to assume that the question is specifically about Redshift.

Redshift is a columnar database where all the column data is stored together but it is broken up into "block" that are 1MB in size.  This is done so that reading a single column doesn't require indexing from a list that is potentially billions of items long.  So each column's data is broken up into 1MB chunks and these chunks have metadata against them to store information about what each block contains.  Two pieces of metadata information are max and min values in the block.

If you want to find a specific ID value in the ID column Redshift can first check the metadata for all the ID column blocks and read only those blocks that could possibly contain the ID you are looking for.  Now if the data store in the table is stored in some random order (wrt ID) then it is likely that the ID you are looking for will be between max and min for ALL block metadata and lots of data needs to be read to find your ID.  However, if your table is sorted by ID then the metadata search will result in only one block needing to be read.  The row numbers for the block in question can be used to find the blocks for other columns so that only limited numbers of blocks need to be read for those columns also.

The other important factor about these blocks is that they are immutable - once written they don't change.  If a block needs to be updated it is replaced entirely.  This is to ensure that at any point in time, for any viewer tables are consistent and that multiple versions of tables of tables can be supported so they users looking at different versions of the table can see consistent data for their version.  (This coherency system is called MVCC - multi-version coherency control.)  The minimum coherent chunk of information in Redshift is the 1MB block.

So in your scenario where tables A and B you are correct that combining these tables is possible.  There is even a command to do this - ALTER TABLE APPEND which takes the blocks from one table and associates them with the other.  A block transplant if you will.  Clearly these tables need to be of the same DDL for this to work.  The metadata for these blocks will also be moved from the source table to the other.  The sourcing table will be empty after this command is run as its blocks have been linked to the other table.

Instead you could just insert the data from one table onto the other.  In this case the sourcing table will contain all its data after the operation.  The "new" rows added will create new blocks in the receiving table and the order of the data will depend on the order of the data written (order by clause in the insert statement for example).  These new blocks, once they have metadata, will have metadata that represents the max and min extents of the data each block has.

Let's assume that in either of these cases that the new data added is also sorted by ID per our example.  The new blocks and the old blocks may have overlapping extents so our search for a specific ID may return two blocks.  Two blocks is still much better than all the blocks.  Still a good situation.

If we want to put the data into perfect sort order on disk we will need to VACUUM the table.  This is the process on Redshift for opening up (potentially) all the blocks of the table to reorder the data and "merge" the row data as you stated.  This will get us back to just one matching block in our ID example.

To answer your question more directly - In Redshift blocks are immutable and all new data added to a table is appended onto the "end" in new blocks.  To "merge" the new data in sort order with the old data the table needs to be VACUUMed.  The vacuum process (potentially) writes all new blocks for the table and once completes the MVCC system changes which version of the table is visible to all users.

Data storage management is very specific for each database design.  This information is for Redshift and MySQL is a different beast with a different architecture.